# How to change the Font Color and Style of a particular String in ListView?

Tags: java, android

I have an Alert Dialog which consists of a ListView. In that list the first option is "Create WatchList". The remaining options in that list are all the other available Watchlist in the app. What I want is :

- To Bolden the "Create Watchlist"
- Change the Colour of "Create WatchList"

[image: Alert Dialog with ListView]

I have already tried 4 methods of achieving this but none of them worked. I put all of my methods in bullet form.

- Storing and formatting "Create WatchList" in strings.xml and calling it from the adapter but it still doesn't work

  `<string name="create_watchlist">&lt;b>Create Watchlist&lt;/b></string>`

  In Java

`String createWatchList = context.getResources().getString(R.string.create_watchlist);`

Then I add it to the List

`alertList.add(0,createWatchList);`

With this above method the text appears with no formatting.

- Then I using fromHtml function but still I got the same results

  `CharSequence styledString = Html.fromHtml(createWatchList );`

  Then I add it to the list
  `alertList.add(0,styledString.toString());`

  Then I tried this in  a text view but it seems that ListViews cannot accept 
  TextViews.
- The Latest I have tried is this:

```
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        int start = 0;
        spannableStringBuilder.append(createWatchlist);
        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFCC5500),start,start+createWatchlist.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),start,start+createWatchlist.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    alertList.add(0,spannableStringBuilder.toString());
```

- I have tried this new method:

```
      TextView textView = new TextView(context);

      textView.setText(createWatchlist);
      textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
      textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightRed));

      alertList.add(0,textView);
```

After trying this new above method I get a message "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'android.widget.TextView', required: 'java.lang.String'"

None of the above methods worked for me. Anyone out there who has any solutions to this please help!!!

Comment: Why don't you just create a custom dialog with RecyclerView, that way you can customize the way you want.
You can follow this article: 
https://medium.com/@makkenasrinivasarao1/android-custom-dialog-with-list-of-items-ba1ab0e78e16

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style and color for the TextView inside the adapter. Just check if it is the first item and do whatever you want with the TextView.

For making it bold:

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD)
```

And for setting a color:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor));
```

Comment: Thank you. But then how do i Pass the TextView to the list? So basically is it like this ```alertList.add(0,textView);```? I have tried this but I get this error "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'android.widget.TextView', required: 'java.lang.String' "

Comment: In this case, I would recommend using a RecyclerView which is a better version of Listview and provides better control. You shouldn't really use ListView anymore. You can find more info in here. It is very straight forward: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java